# Formulas in PHP

Tags: php, excel, formula

To a person skilled in programming, I know this question might seem ridiculous, but please bear with me.  I'm involved in a court case and a critical point hinges on the answer to a couple of questions.

Given a mathematical formula, along with complete formula documentation as shown here:
[alt text http://img69.imageshack.us/img69/1937/formula.png](http://img69.imageshack.us/img69/1937/formula.png)
(Pixelated some of the descriptors)

1. In solving the equation for P, is there ANY requirement or need to implement the formula in Microsoft Excel prior to implementing it in PHP source code?
2. Could a competent PHP programmer just type the formula into PHP source code without the use of Microsoft Excel in the interim?

Thank you very much!

Comment: Do I need to speak to my attorney before answering this question?

Comment: LOL...  No, this isn't for testimony, it's simply to show my attorney that the other side is on crack.  Feel free to answer if you can add to it.  :-)

Comment: wtf does Excel have to do with **basic math**? The only case in which it might be related is if it relies on an Excel specific calculation error (it's ridden with those), but even in that case, the other side is on crack.

Comment: The other side is on crack for even introducing excel here. Any one remotely familiar with programming brought to testify in this court will agree that excel has nothing to do with this.

Excel is a program by ONE vendor, of course that's not going to be related to general math questions. Also, a lot of programmers tend to eschew Microsoft software, and have a unfavourable opinion towards it because it's not open source and caters to laymen.

Comment: If your lawyer doesn't realize the ridiculousness of this then you might want to find one more suited towards programming cases.

Comment: I really hope the responses here can help you, I also showed this to a mate of mine who always rants about judges having to judge over fields they have no competence in whatsoever, he said 'Wow, if he loses this, I lost my confidence in the world.'

Really, for any programmer the claim that Excel is some-how a requirement is beyond this world.

Comment: Maybe they should bring Texas Instruments into the case too since the T-83 can calculate these formulas.

Comment: LMAO - Thanks folks!  I'm passing this along.  I've been doing PHP since 1999, v3.  This is so laughable, but the other side keeps making claim that Excel is somehow required - against expert testimony.  Anyhoo - thanks so much!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The formulas you have presented are remedial mathematics, any decent programmer with any programming language (including PHP) could implement those formulas without Excel or any other software aid.  So the answers to your questions are:

1.) NO

2.) YES

Answer (score 8):

1: No, I (and many here) probably really would not get the use of excel.
2: Absolutely.

A thing you have to realize though is that programming languages seldom deal in 'equations', they aren't 'symmetric' as in maths, the right side *evaluates* to the left.

Comment: So you have to be very explicit.  Use parentheses liberally.

Answer (score 4):

I haven't tested this but I didn't use anything to write this. Just this message box and the image above. I did this to show how simple it would be to write the code that implements these formulas in a matter of minutes.

```
<?php
$C  = 1;
$I  = 2;
$N  = 3;
$T  = 4;
$TA = 5;
$Q  = 6;
$E  = 7;
$L  = 8;
$D  = 9;

$i = 1.0/12.0;
$v = 1.0/(1.0+$i);
$f = (1.0+$i)/(1.0+($i*$Q/30.0));
$a = ((1.0 - pow($v, $N))/$i)*$f;
$b = (1.0 - pow($v, $N+$T))/$i;
$ff = ($E - $Q)/30.0;
$aa = $A*$ff;
$j = $D*$TA/100.0;
$k = (($L*$T)/(600.0*($T+1.0))) * ((($T-$a+$b)/$i)+$aa);
$P = $C / ($a - $j - $k);
echo $P;
?>
```

Answer (score 2):

There's no reason whatsoever to use Excel before implementing this in PHP. Though it might help someone who wanted to use Excel for some basic calculations to see variations on input values, one skilled in PHP could just code in the variables and formulas directly.

Comment: You could also use the Open Office program to do this

Answer (score 0):

I guess I'll be the contrarian.

> In solving the equation for P, is there ANY requirement or need to implement the formula in Microsoft Excel prior to implementing it in PHP source code?

While there's no need to implement the formulas in Microsoft Excel prior to implementing it in PHP source code, because of the number and complexity of the formulas, a developer may have used Excel to see all of the intermediate results before coding the formulas into PHP.

The original implementation might have been in Excel, and after a period of time when the users were comfortable with the results, the formulas were recoded in PHP.

> Could a competent PHP programmer just type the formula into PHP source code without the use of Microsoft Excel in the interim?

Yes.

Comment: The original implementation could also have been on a napkin.  The question was if Excel MUST be used for to develop/calculate these formulas, not if it were possible to use Excel on these formulas.

Comment: Going back further, the calculations were probably done with a calculator and, even further back, by hand.  I quoted the question, and answered it honestly, based on the words "ANY requirement or need".

Comment: To see some of the calculations' results before coding PHP, any number of aids could be used. Excel, OpenOffice, a calculator, a napkin (as typoknig suggested (p.s. love the name)), or carved into a restaurant table somewhere. Excel's just one tool out there amongst many others.

Comment: typoknig & JYelton, you're both being logical.  I'm trying to be lawyerly. :-)

Comment: Yes, and perhaps I should have been more clear - instead of "ANY", I should have put my lawyer hat on and said "AN ABSOLUTE"  :-)